# PHPMailler Anexo com Tmp name

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou com o seguinte código em PHP, utilizando o PHPMailer para enviar por e-mail arquivos de um upload múltiplo, está funcionando o problema é que no e-mail o nome dos arquivos fica com o nome da pasta tmp por exemplo : "/tmp/php/Z9MDY7" ao invés de aparecer o nome do arquivo que foi anexado, porém na pasta do servidor para onde vão esses mesmo arquivos o nome está correto, o que poderia ser?

Código:

```
$total = count($_FILES['pdfanexo']['name']);

for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {                                              
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['pdfanexo']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newFilePath = "Marcas/" .$vregistro. $d. "/". $_FILES['pdfanexo']['name'][$i];
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {            
            $mail->addAttachment($newFilePath, $tmpFilePath);       //Attachment Documentos Múltiplo Upload (PDF-DOCUMENT)  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A declaração do método addAttachment é:

```
/**
 * Add an attachment from a path on the filesystem.
 * Returns false if the file could not be found or read.
 * @param string $path Path to the attachment.
 * @param string $name Overrides the attachment name.
 * @param string $encoding File encoding (see $Encoding).
 * @param string $type File extension (MIME) type.
 * @param string $disposition Disposition to use
 * @throws phpmailerException
 * @return bool
*/
public function addAttachment($path, $name = '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = '', $disposition = 'attachment')
```

E você está passando o `$tmpFilePath` ao invés do nome do arquivo no segundo parâmetro. Tente realizar a troca abaixo:

De:

```
$mail->addAttachment($newFilePath, $tmpFilePath);
```

Para:

```
$mail->addAttachment($newFilePath, $_FILES['pdfanexo']['name'][$i]);
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!